# How to break after if statement using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have an ajax list in WordPress. Everytime I click one of the links there will be an ajax request to filter products.

I want to toggle the `addClass` and `removeClass` every time a link from the list is click toggled.

My script below only works only on ajaxComplete

```
j( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {

  j('.woof_radio_label').click(function(myEvent) {
    if(j(this).siblings('.woof_radio_term').is(':checked')) {
      j('.page-content-wrap').removeClass('open');
      j(this).siblings('.woof_radio_term_reset').click();
    } else {
      j('.page-content-wrap').addClass('open');
    }
  });

});
```

When I hit the if condition, it executes the else statement on the website. Do you know what code can i put so that else statement won't execute?

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: if you dont want to display else, then you can remove else right?

Comment: If you just do return; it will out from the current scope.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking / the cause.  If you don't want the else statement, then just comment it out?  It seems strange to keep adding another click handler every time ajax completes. Maybe it's running too many times?

Comment: I want to return the else statement again so I can include the addClass again...

Comment: create a fiddle

Comment: @ConanCarroll you can simpy trigger the click from your code.

Comment: @ConanCarroll your code is bind a event on every ajaxComplete, Please correct me if I think it's not proper.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta you were right. i was able to solve this problem by binding an event to .on. the code will run correctly even if it is not on ajaxcomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve issue by binding an event to a `.on()` method. It works even for elements that were created dynamically.

The code below is now executed inside document ready and not inside ajaxComplete

```
j(document).on('click', '.woof_sid_woof-categories .woof_list_radio > li > .woof_childs_list > li > .woof_childs_list > li .woof_radio_label', function(e) {
    if(j(this).siblings('.woof_radio_term').is(':checked')) {
      j('.page-content-wrap').removeClass('open');
      j(this).siblings('.woof_radio_term_reset').click();
    } else {
      j('.page-content-wrap').addClass('open');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For your case, you should use return false to stop.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: You can't use break statement in if,else, it's for inside the loop